# Why is my class instance saving the final value after each iteration when I pass through a list instead of a float or integer?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, instance

I want to create an instance method that contains a function that modifies one of the variables inside the instance, and then iterate this operation multiple times. Here is a sample of my code:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, counter):
        self.x = counter

    def func(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1


def routine(dat):
    t1 = test(dat)

    print('Initial Count: ', t1.x)

    for i in range(3):
        t1.func()

    print('Final Count: ', t1.x)

def main(dat):

    for i in range(3):
        print('Iter; ', i, 'Init Value: ', dat)
        routine(dat)
        print('Iter; ', i, 'Final Value: ', dat)

D = 0
main(D)
```

If I pass through the integer D to the method t1 and call the function func() three times, then the integer increases by 3. If I run this three times, as shown in the function main(), and do not change the variable dat between iterations, then dat does not change between iterations. Furthermore, the variable self.x resets every time as shown here:

[image: Final result 1]

This is working as expected.

However, if I set D to be a list containing an integer, `D=[0]`, and modify the function func() accordingly:

```
def func(self):
    self.x[0] = self.x[0] + 1
```

so that I am incrementing the value inside the list, then self.x does not reset in between iterations and it seems that the variable dat inside the function main() now behaves as if it is a global variable. If you run the code accounting for this modification, you get this:

[image: Final result 2]

Why is my code behaving this way? And what do I need to do so that the modified version behaves the similarly to the previous version? I want to pass through an array, manipulate values inside the array, output the results, and then do it all over again using the same initial conditions.

## Update

Thank you for the responses. The reason for this behavior is that lists are mutable. I instead need to set D to be a tuple and recreate the list inside the method. The modifications are as follows:

`D = (0,)`

```
def __init__(self, counter):
    self.x = [i for i in counter]
```

Comment: Because containers are mutable and integers are not. When you modify an integer you are replacing it's reference in only the scope where it is changed. The code calling the function will still have the old reference.

Comment: I guess I naively assumed that the method t1 is recreated after each iteration. What should I do to make sure that the input list is immutable?

Comment: I would have `main` create the instance of the `test` class, and pass that to `routine`. This way test is only created once, and the `test.x` will be preserved between iterations.

Comment: In this case I will be modifying the same method over and over again, when instead I want to recreate t1 from scratch every time. Each iteration should be independent. I think I need to create an entirely different list inside t1 that contains all the values of D every time. Or contain that local list inside a reset function that is called once routine() is finished. I wish there was a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the `variable referencing` mechanism.
Let's go step by step.
I would recommend reading one of my [articles](https://probhakar-95.medium.com/are-python-functions-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference-6d28991df1b1?source=your_stories_page-------------------------------------)

`case-1` D = 0
so `D` is an integer. Integers are immutable.

```py
D = 0
A = D
A += 1
print(A) # it will print 1
print(D) # it will print 0
```

`case-1` D = [0]
D is a `list`. Lists are mutable.

```py
D = [0]
A = D
A[0] += 1
print(A) # it will print [1]
print(B) # it will print [1]
```

Comment: Thanks! So one solution is to instead pass the integer inside the list to self.x instead of entire list. Another solution to keep self.x as a list while also preserving immutability is to create a local list inside the method. For example, self.x = [counter[0]]. This works but it is not elegant. Is there a better solution?

Comment: The second won't help because each time `routine()` function is called a `new` test object will be created with fresh variables. You can try `global variables` but it is not recommended.

Comment: What you are trying to do is similar to `pass by reference` in C. But python works in a different way. The closest approximation is `[0]` to my understanding.

Comment: Got it! I set D to be a tuple and then generate a list inside t1.